# Guestbook for Craft

Tags: plugins, craft-features

I need a guestbook for a website.

I tried this plugin:

> https://github.com/verbb/comments

but it doesn't work.
And I also tried this:

> https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form

But my changes will not be save. And I don't, if this is the right way to build a guestbook.

Is there an other plugin for Craft?

Or any idea how i can build a guestbook in Craft?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built one using a channel and the Guest Entries plugin. You can easily create whatever fields you want. I'd Name, Comments, Reply, IP Address, verified. 
Or are you after something more complex?